# Trying to connect to an Oracle server v9.2.0.8 with the pycharm database tool

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, pycharm, oracle9i

I'm trying to use the PyCharm database tool to look at a couple of Oracle databases. The first database is an Oracle 11 database and connects with no problems. The second database, however, is an Oracle 9i database and is giving me issues. When i try to connect to it I get an error message that says

> Unsupported combination of server/driver versions: found Oracle server version 9.2.0.8 with JDBC driver version 12.1.0.2 that is not compatible. Oracle server version 9.x must be connected by JDBC driver versions 9.x to 11.x..

I've tried finding where pycharm keeps the JDBC drivers but have had no luck. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. I would also appreciate it if someone could point me towards where I can download drivers that will work with the Oracle 9i and 11(g i think?) databases.

I'm on windows 10 64 bit and using PyCharm 2016.2.3.

Comment: You can download the drivers from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Oracle Server 9i- 9.2.0.4.
To query on this server I am using Jet Brains DataGrip.
It showed me the same error and then I changed driver jar of ojdbc6-x.x.x with
ojdbc14-9.2.0.1.jar and then It started working fine on DataGrip.
Hope this will be helpful.

Download ojdbc14-9.2.01 and configure it on your local Database management tool.
  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadojdbc149201jar.htm